# Touchscreen not releasing 'mousedown' event - possible to resolve?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse, dell, touchscreen

With a Dell XPS 15 9560 laptop and Ubuntu 18 LTS (with current update of the kernel), sometimes the keyboard becomes unresponsive. The mouse moves, the UI responds to hover actions, and moving the mouse hightlights text (without pressing the mouse buttons).

It resolves itself if I tap the touch screen (which is squeaky clean).

Is there a fix for this (ideally without disabling the touch screen)?

(Related: [ubuntu 18 unity keyboard (not mouse) freeze, lightdm restart borks system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096911/ubuntu-18-unity-keyboard-not-mouse-freeze-lightdm-restart-borks-system))